# Visual Studio Code Editor Jumps on Undo (Randomly)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, undo, code-editor

This is driving me nuts.

I'm using VS 2013 and CTL+Z code editor behavior is just plain unbearable.

What I mean is that the code editor jumps sometimes on UNDO. Sometimes the text carriage is at the top of the screen, sometimes at the bottom.

Most annoying is when you hit undo inline a few times, the first few times everything is fine but then on Nth time it will randomly jump the screen and move the current line to top or bottom of the screen.

This makes code editing a huge pain. Any way to correct this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to turn it off, but I finally realized what it's doing. It jumps to the top to mark a place where you recompiled. So if you do edit, edit, edit, compile, edit, edit, then the third undo will jump to the top, and the fourth will continue with undoing.